# undefined href attribute value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, href

I want the href value, but this gives me undefined, why is that?

```
var hy = $('.Player a.sc-player').attr('href');

console.log(hy);

<div id="Container">
  <header>
    <div id="Player">
      <div class="Player">
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/rapzilla/andy-mineo-stop-the-traffic" class="sc-player"></a>
        <p>hellow</p>
        <a href="" class="download_song">Download</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/Player-->
  </header>**strong text**
```

Comment: You cant combine both values in one variable

Comment: can you included jquery lib?

Comment: I ran your code and it is logging the href value, not undefined.

Comment: Wrap in `$(function() { var hy = $('.Player a.sc-player').attr('href'); });`

Comment: Use the code inside `jQuery(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    alert($('.Player a.sc-player').attr('href'))
});
```